# Can I create 'jump points' in visual studio 2005?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I am working with a visual studio 2005 project with several thousand lines of code.
When I am looking at an `IF` statement in the code is there anyway to jump to the corresponding `ELSE` part without scrolling through hundreds of lines of code? I can't use `goto` as the line numbers will change all the time. If I can't automatically jump to the `else` part of an `if` statement, can I set up something to allow me to tag the `else` part and then go to that tag in visual studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`]`</kbd> to jump to the matching brace or parenthesis. So you can place your cursor on the brace of the `if` statement and press the shortcut to go to the end of the block and thus directly in front of the `else`.

Another option would be to set bookmarks with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>. Those move when the line moves as well and you can jump between them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: hi - i'm using vb.net so there aren't any curly braces. Does it still work. I tried putting the cursor in all sorts of places around the if statement and pressing ctrl-J but to no avail. Thanks for your answer

Comment: It's Ctrl+], i.e. closing square bracket, not J. It probably doesn't work in VB.NET. That leaves you the bookmarks.